# How to get a large number of documents in a single request in solr?

Tags: java, web-services, solr, solrj

How are you friends?

I need help on solr, I currently have a query system and I use solr as a search engine, to be honest it works excellently.
The problem, a requirement arose where I have to request all the existing records, these are more than 1,500,000.
This becomes a bit complicated since apparently solr stops responding or marks me an error in the service after a time of waiting on that request.

I need help, I want to know if someone knows how to divide the records or any alternative to obtain large volumes of documents at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the `/export` endpoint which is built for exporting large datasets? Another alternative is using the `csv` request writer, which is far quicker for large datasets.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch all 1.5 million records at once or via pagination?

Comment: No friend MatsLindh, I have not yet tested the time it takes with the requestHandler export, I already implemented the lines in the solrconfig, do you know how it works or why would everything return faster?

Comment: That's right friend Hector, I'm trying to retrieve all the records at once to build a csv, without using pagination.